# Method Attribute access to Method boundries

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

in a custom method attribute is there is any way to access the method and execute some code before the method body ? and at the end of the method body ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Would only be possible with AOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword to look for is Aspect oriented programming (AOP). One implementation that can be used to do what you want is [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp).

Comment: i know the OnMethodBoundaryAspect of PostSharp but postsharp is too much to put in my application plus its not free and complicated , i was trying to make my own simple attribute which will allow me to log entry of a method and the out of it.

Comment: any other solution (AOP) which free ?